# excel saves a downloaded CSV with tab separation , but weirdly not at all times

Tags: download

When I try to open and save a downloaded csv file , excel replaces the commas with tabs. Ok . But not for all files.

Users of my web application can download 2 different csv files ( one for error scenario and other for success). Both have same format. Both downloads are handled by almost same code in the server , contains similar HTTP response headers including content types. I expect the user to correct the error file and save and upload. but when they save(Ctrl+S) using excel , it simply replaces commas to tabs.

**Here is the weirdness:** It doesn't happen for success file. When I Ctrl+S a success file , its getting saved fine.

Note :

- Both files have same format. I even tried the use case where the error and success files are identical . Compared using Winmerge and they are same, including whitespaces
- If you just open and save the error file using a text editor once , thereafter excel handles the file just fine. Doesn't remove commas upon saving.
- mime types for the files are same as per file -I output  ( text/plain ; charset=us-ascii ).Response headers & content types during download are same (text/csv)
- happens with all browsers, on windows as well as MacOS.

Here are the sample files.You should be able to download them and reproduce the error. They are identical too.

[Success file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwWNuroXMXnEUmxobkdEb28xYjg/view?usp=sharing)

[Error File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwWNuroXMXnEWHdwekFkdWNZRkE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The root cause we found is that the BOM ( byte object marker) is set to UTF-8 on the success file , but not on the error file.  Weird why it caused this issue .